# Print Microsoft Project chart as giant PDF

Tags: pdf, print-to-pdf, microsoft-project-2007

I have Adobe's PDF creator installed and I'm using Microsoft Project 2007... I want to print my gantt chart as one giant single-page PDF. (Currently it's set to print on letter sized paper, and it's six pages in a 3x2 layout.)

I can't figure out where or how to make those settings. The PDF page setup doesn't seem to be right, nor "page setup" in Project.

Help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first define the paper output size. Then I hope this helps: [Changing print options for Project 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project/HA102202231033.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a custom page size in the Adobe printer settings. You may need to click on the `Advanced Settings` button and select the page size option in the tree list.